# CSS change style base on valid input

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and I will appreciate any help.

I'm trying to style the asterisk `*` inside the `span` element of a required element based on the `input:valid` property.

```
<input value="someValue" id="firstnameId" required />
<label class="lbStyle" for="FirstName">
    First Name
    <span class="ddff" style="color:red;">*</span>
</label>
```

I tried to do :

```
input:valid .ddff {
    color: palegreen;
}
```

But it's not working.

I want to change the color of the `*` from red to green if the input is valid or keep it red otherwise.

How can I achieve it using CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: In your span you have an inline css. It overwrite your css rule, so you can remove it or set your color into css like this input:valid .ddff {
      color: palegreen !important
 }

Comment: Can you change the HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css is inline, try with `!important`

```css
input:valid + label .ddff {
      color: palegreen !important;
 }
```

```html
<input value="someValue" id="firstnameId" required />
   <label class="lbStyle" for="FirstName"> First Name
    <span class="ddff" style="color:red;">*</span>
</label>
```

Comment: please don't use `!important`

Comment: @xmastertje  inline CSS how can overwrite?

Comment: The initial red color of the span should not be inline here in the first place, and then no !important is needed either.

Comment: Thank you!!
I removed the inline style and the !important also and it works great!
I can't vote for you @04FS because I newbie and I dont have that option here.
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:valid` and `:invalid` selector for form elements with limitation such as required.

Try this:

```css
input[required]:invalid + label:after{content:"*";color:red}
input[required]:valid + label:after{content:"*";color:green}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Placeholder" required />
<label> First Name</label>
```

Comment: this is the best answer, but the input should have the someValue as placeholder text

Comment: You can add default value as you want. If add value, input will be :valid at first

Comment: It's not ideal to start off with the asterisk showing as valid. Placeholder text is recommended if user input is required

Comment: Use placeholder instead

Answer (score 0):

it can works because `.ddff` is not an input child

```
<input value="someValue" id="firstnameId" required />
   <label class="lbStyle" for="FirstName"> First Name
    <span class="ddff">*</span>
</label>

.ddff{
      color: red;
}
input:valid + label .ddff {
      color: green;
 }

input:invalid +label .ddff {
      color: red;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The first comment helped me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is not correct, you have to use the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```css
input + label .ddff {
    color: red;
}

input:valid + label .ddff {
    color: palegreen;
}
```

```html
<input value="someValue" id="firstnameId" required />
<label class="lbStyle" for="FirstName">
    First Name
    <span class="ddff">*</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try:

CSS:

```
input:valid + label span.ddff {
      color: palegreen !important;
 }
```

Note: You can use an inline CSS. please overwrite your CSS.